# Boost condition variable

Tags: c++, boost

I would like to use boost condition variable as synchronization mechanizm, but in that case:

```
boost::condition_variable cond;
boost::mutex              mutex;

void worker_func()
{
    cond.notify_all();
    std::cout << "After notify" << std::endl;
}

void main()
{
    boost::mutex::soped_lock lock(mutex);
    boost::thread work(worker_func);
    boost::this_thread::sleep_for(boost::chrono::milliseonds(500));
    cond.wait(lock); // here is deadlock
}
```

when we 'fire' condition before we wait for that condition there is deadlock. If there is a good solution to write wrapper which provide bool atomic which 'remember' that condition was previously fired or there is some other better way to do that ?

Example of wrapper:

```
class Cond_wrap
{
private:
    boost::condition_variable cond;
    boost::mutex              mutex;
    bool work_to_do;
public:
    Cond_wrap()
    {
        boost::mutex::scoped_lock(mutex);
        work_to_do = false; 
    }
    void notify_all()
    {
        boost::mutex::scoped_lock(mutex);
        work_to_do = true;
        cond.notify_all();
    }
    void wait()
    {
        boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(mutex);
        if(!work_to_do)
        {
            cond.wait(lock);
            work_to_do = true;
        }
        else
        {
            return;
        }
    }
    bool timed_wait(unsigned int timeout)
    {
        boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(mutex);
        if(!work_to_do)
        {
            if(cond.timed_wait(lock, boost::chrono::milliseonds(timeout)))
            {
                work_to_do = true;
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
};

Cond_wrap condition_wrap;

void worker_func()
{
    {
        condition_wrap.notify_all();
    }
    std::cout << "After notify" << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    boost::thread work(worker_func);
    work.detach();

    {
        boost::this_thread::sleep_for(boost::chrono::milliseonds(500));
        condition_wrap.wait();
        //there is work to do
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `main` needs an `int` return type.

Answer (score 3):

That's not how condition variables work. A condition variable should have a condition associated. That condition is evaluated with the mutex held, so no races are possible, and thus you don't need the wait.

Note that this condition is also needed for the possibility of spurious wake-ups.

Also the condition variable should be notified from the thread that holds the lock. And probably it is not a good idea to spawn new threads with the lock held. I like to add braces to state clearly the scope of the locked code.

```
boost::condition_variable cond;
boost::mutex              mutex;
bool work_to_do = false;

void worker_func()
{
    {
        boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(mutex);
        work_to_do = true,
        cond.notify_all();
    }
    std::cout << "After notify" << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    boost::thread work(worker_func);

    {
        boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(mutex);
        boost::this_thread::sleep_for(boost::chrono::milliseonds(500));
        while (!work_to_do)
            cond.wait(lock); // no deadlock
        //there is work to do
        work_to_do = false;
    }
}
```

Note how in my code the `work_to_do` variable is always used with the lock held, as is the call to `notify_all()`. Also, note that `cond.wait()` is called in a loop, so that spurious wake-ups will not spoil the fun.

PS. just say no to `void main()`.

Comment: It is ok, to create wrapper just like in my first post ? (first post was edited because in 'quick reply there is only a few characters').

Thanks all for help.

Comment: I think it is wrong. You replaced the `while` with an `if`, but you need the loop (for the spurious wake-ups). And you are setting `work_to_do=true` in `wait()`, while it should be `work_to_do=false`. The `else return;` is pretty useless. You do not need the `scoped_lock()` in the constructor because constructors are not run concurrently. You are missing a few variable names: `boost::mutex::scoped_lock(mutex);` does nothing useful! All that said, you can write a wrapper that does what you want, but it is not a good format for a SO question, more for CodeReview...

Comment: Here is continuation on CodeReview:
http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/96927/boost-condition-variable-wrapper

thanks you for advices, but probably I cannot use while in timed_wait because I only want to wait for condition in my timeout, so it is ok to use if in timed_wait ? I want to have similar functionality to windows event -> waitforsingleobject(event, timeout) if condition is not set, or it will not be set in timeout we move on.

Answer (score 1):

Unlike windows events, condition variables do not have any state because it is a *mechanism* for waiting and notifying. There can also be spurious wake-ups.

You must associate some state with condition variables. See examples at http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable.

Answer (score 0):

To use a condition variable, you need 3 things.

A condition variable, a mutex, and a variable.

When operating on the other two elements, you lock the mutex.

When you want to send a message to waiters, lock the mutex, set the variable, then notify using the condition variable.  (in some cases unlock mutex before notify: check your docs)

When you want to get messages, lock the mutex, check the variable, and wait on the condition.  Spurious wakeups may be possible (check your docs), so when you wake up recheck the variable.

This is based off knowledge of C++11 `std` condition variable, hence the "check your docs" comments.

Comment: I've always thought that you should notify the condvar witht the mutex locked or you risk some races in some corner cases. Do you know of any situation where it is useful to notify with the mutex unlocked?

Comment: @rodrigo uncertain.  I have read someone saying that their tests showed performance issues.  The core idea is to have the mutex locked when probing the variable, and that a notification isn't complete until you check the variable.  Maybe there is a problem where not having the mutex locked when you notify, but I don't know of it.

Comment: Ah, here: *"The notifying thread does not need to hold the lock on the same mutex as the one held by the waiting thread(s); in fact doing so is a pessimization, since the notified thread would immediately block again, waiting for the notifying thread to release the lock. However, some implementations (in particular many implementations of pthreads) recognize this situation and avoid this "hurry up and wait" scenario by transferring the waiting thread from the condition variable's queue directly to the queue of the mutex within the notify call, without waking it up.*"

Comment: Ah, well, that is the technical requirement about `notify()` you are not required to hold a lock to call `cond.notify()`. But in the example linked, if you had several `signals()` and several `waits()` I think that it would be racy...

Comment: @rodrigo It is ok to be scared, but if by "racy" means there can be a race condition, I think you are wrong?  The premature pessimization of "the other thread wakes up, then locks immediately, then wakes up later" isn't something to ignore.

Comment: The race would depend on the intended semantics of the program, and the example is to simple to make anything of it. Anyway, that pessimization makes no sense to me. The other thread does not need to be awaken when `notify()` is called if the mutex is held. It looks to me like a particular implementation had a performance bug and someone noted it in the documentation of the language.

Comment: @rodrigo To avoid that, it requires that mutexes understand condition variables that have been fired on their waiting objects?  Ie, the unlocking of the mutex "fires off" the "deferred" condition variable notification (deferred, because it detected that the target was holding the same mutex as the originating thread), which actually causes the thread waiting on "both" to wake up?  That seems like a lot of (seemingly pointless) work.  Can you actually provide a race condition example?  You talk about being wary of one, but if the cv is all about nodifying value changes, I don't see it.

Comment: Yakk: I cannot think of any race, but I found this relevant [Wikipedia quote](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monitor_(synchronization)): _It is usually considered a best practice to perform the "signal"/"notify" operation before releasing mutex[...], but as long as the code is properly designed for concurrency[...], it is often also acceptable to release the lock before signalling.  Depending on the threading implementation, the ordering of this can have scheduling-priority ramifications. (Some[...] advocate a preference for releasing the lock before signalling.)_